# Multi select, no consigo hacerlo funcionar con BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, select

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario de edición, en el cual hay un campo que es un multi-select, para seleccionar los servicios que tiene esa propiedad.

La estructura de la BD, es tal como os indico.

**TABLA VIVIENDA**

vivienda_id

**TABLA SERVICIO**

servicio_id | nombre

**TABLA VIVIENDA_SERVICIO**

vivienda_vivienda_id | servicio_servicio_id

De la tabla vivienda_servicio, saco los servicios que tiene cada vivienda.

**En el archivo EDITAR-VIVIENDA-ALQUILER.php**

Aquí tengo esta consulta para rellenar los `value` del formulario

```
$idget = $_GET['ID'];
$results = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT vi.vivienda_id, vi.localidad, vi.metrosUtiles,
        vi.construccion, vi.referencia, vi.ciudad,
        vi.nombre, vi.foto, vi.estado_id, vi.etiqueta_id,
        vi.precio, vi.metros, vi.habitaciones, vi.aseos,
        vi.banos, vi.descripcion, vi.cliente_id, vi.terraza,
        vi.orientacion,vi.plantas, vi.altura,
        vi.estadoVivienda, vi.comunidad, vi.home, et.etiqueta_id,
        et.etiqueta AS nombreETQ, es.estado_id, es.estado,
        cl.cliente_id, cl.nombre AS name, cl.apellido
        FROM vivienda AS vi
        LEFT JOIN  etiqueta AS et ON vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id
        INNER JOIN estado AS es ON vi.estado_id = es.estado_id
        LEFT JOIN cliente AS cl ON vi.cliente_id = cl.cliente_id
        where vi.estado_id = 1 and vi.vivienda_id = $idget;
");
if($res = $results->fetch_array())
```

Luego tengo en multi-select con una consulta para sacar los servicios que tiene esa vivienda y poder añadir más o bien quitar.

```
<select id="select2-2" class="form-control" name="servicios" multiple>
    <?php
        $vivienda = $mysqli->query("
            SELECT viS.vivienda_vivienda_id,
                viS.servicio_servicio_id,
                serv.servicio_id, serv.nombre
                FROM vivienda_servicio AS viS
                RIGHT JOIN  servicio AS serv
                ON viS.servicio_servicio_id = serv.servicio_id;
        ");

        foreach ($vivienda as $viv){
            ?><option value='<?php echo $viv['servicio_id']; ?>' <?php
            if(trim($viv['vivienda_vivienda_id'])==$res['vivienda_id']){ 
                ?> selected<?php
            } ?>><?php echo $viv['nombre']; ?></option><?php
        }?>
</select>
```

La cuestión es que me ralentiza el navegador y además me duplica todos los servicios, luego por otro lado no consigo bien guardarlos pero ese es otro tema, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Buen día Miguel, por lo que veo en tu sentencia del multiselect no hay una cláusula WHERE que llame los servicios de la vivienda, con la sentencia actual que tienes estás llamando a todos los servicios de todas las viviendas.

Comment: Ok entiendo, pero no se bien como solucionarlo @Eliseo

Comment: Me gusta la pregunta. Modifícala enviándonos la base de datos en SQL con algún registro de ejemplo (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) para hacer las comprobaciones y dinos qué esperas obtener en el desplegable a partir de los datos que aportas como ejemplo. Así podremos ayudarte a realizar la query correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Miguel, ¿has abandonado esta pregunta? Hemos quedado a la espera de más datos para poder ayudarte

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por la ayuda, anoche consegui solventarlo, ahora publico la solución que le encontre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado de este modo.

```
<?php
  $servicios = $mysqli->query("SELECT s.nombre, s.servicio_id FROM servicio s");

  foreach ($servicios as $servicio){
    $viviendaConServicio = $mysqli->query("SELECT vs.vivienda_vivienda_id FROM vivienda_servicio vs WHERE vs.vivienda_vivienda_id = $idget AND vs.servicio_servicio_id = ".$servicio['servicio_id']);

    $viviendaConServicio = $viviendaConServicio->fetch_array();
    echo json_encode($viviendaConServicio);                                         
    if(isset($viviendaConServicio['vivienda_vivienda_id'])){
  ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $servicio['servicio_id']; ?>' selected><?php echo $servicio['nombre']; ?></option>

    <?php
     }else{      
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $servicio['servicio_id']; ?>"><?php echo $servicio['nombre']; ?></option>
    <?php
     }
    ?>
    <?php } ?><?php
      $servicios = $mysqli->query("SELECT s.nombre, s.servicio_id FROM servicio s");

      foreach ($servicios as $servicio){
       $viviendaConServicio = $mysqli->query("SELECT vs.vivienda_vivienda_id FROM vivienda_servicio vs WHERE vs.vivienda_vivienda_id = $idget AND vs.servicio_servicio_id = ".$servicio['servicio_id']);

       $viviendaConServicio = $viviendaConServicio->fetch_array();
       echo json_encode($viviendaConServicio);

       if(isset($viviendaConServicio['vivienda_vivienda_id'])){
      ?>
       <option value='<?php echo $servicio['servicio_id']; ?>' selected><?php echo $servicio['nombre']; ?></option>

      <?php
        }else{
      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $servicio['servicio_id']; ?>"><?php echo $servicio['nombre']; ?></option>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
      <?php } ?>
```